# Different output on different format of adding a new char to string

Tags: string, char, string-concatenation

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
{
     string name[] = {"Geeks ", "for", "Geeks"} ;
     string v,s ;

     v += name[0][0] + "." ;
     cout << v << "\n" ;

     s += name[0][0] ;
     s += "." ;
     cout << s << "\n" ;
}
```

On outputting:

string v outputs a garbage string while string s outputs G.

Output :

@ // output of string v

G. // output of string s

Why does v give out a garbage value even though I'm appending '.' to the new string ?

Kindly explain both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Clang will complain about:

```
v += name[0][0] + "." ;
```

with a message like:

```
warning: adding 'std::...' (aka 'char') to a string does not append to the string [-Wstring-plus-int]
```

In other words, `string + "chars"` does not append the `chars` to the string, and so you need to create the string manually:

```
v += name[0][0] + string(".") ;
```